# How to make an inner class

Tags: java, arrays, class

Here is the task

> You owner of restaurant. you have maximum 5 tables. Each table has orders, which consists from name of the dishes and their numbers.You need to realize datastructure to manage it.

So it should be a main class and one more class with tables (tables should be counting in array), inside class Tables should be a class Orders, and inside this Orders should be two arrays with names of orders and count of orders(how many "fish" i would order). In general i should have three arrays and the output should be something like this: "Table 1 ordered 2 salads", " Table 2 ordered 3 milk" and so on

I start from this

```
public class Lesson8Task4 {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Tables[] table1 = new Tables[1];

    System.out.println(table1);

}
public static class Tables {
    int[] tablesCount = {1 , 2, 3, 4, 5};
    public static String[] ordersName = {"potatoes", "coke", "meat", "fish", "milk"};
    public static int[] dishNumber = {1,2,3,4,5};
}
```

}

I hope I explain lucidly.
Thanks

Comment: Take a look at [ask]

Comment: you post is unhelpful

Comment: It's helpful if you read it and edit your question accordingly.

Comment: I have downvoted this question because you have posted code on here without specifying what is wrong with it.  We expect to see what you expect the code to do, why you expect it to do this, and what it is actually doing.  Please [edit] your question to include this information, and then I will consider retracting my downvote.  See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: I expect this "How to make class inside another class, with acess to array"

Comment: We're not here to do your homework for you.

Comment: but everyone are here to help other people, isn't it ? and I cannot understand how to do it and need any help, I don't ask to to write all the code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I will try to explain it to you without code, since I think you should learn from yourself.
You have an array `table1` that can only have an element in position 0.
**You need to give a value to that position** like this: `table1[0] = new Tables();` now it depends on the complexity you have but with what you posted I would just do a `for` from 0 to `table1[0].tablesCount.length` and inside the for a  with **something like this**: `System.out.println("Table "+table1[0].tablesCount[i]....)`
I belive in you ;)